# Java Multiplication Table how to prompt user for rows etc

Tags: java

I need to prompt the user to enter a number 1 through 5. This is the size of the multiplication table. If a user puts in a number greater than 5 or a negative number, then program tells them they have input an invalid number and prompts them again, and if the user enters 0, then stop the execution of the program.  Can someone help me write this part?

What I have so far:

```
// Beginning of class MultiplicationTable
public class MultiplicationTable {      

// Beginning of method main
public static void main(String[] args) {    

    /* Declare and initialize primitive variables */
    int result;

    /* Header */
    // First, print some space
    System.out.print("    ");

    // Then, print numbers from 1 to 5 across the top
    for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {
        System.out.print("    " + j); 
    }
    System.out.println();

    /* Separator */
    // Print a dashed line
    for (int j = 1; j < 50; j++) {
        System.out.print("-");
    }   
    System.out.println();

    /* Values */
    // Outer loop: multipliers
    for (int outer = 1; outer <= 5; outer++) {  
        System.out.print(outer + " | ");

        // Inner loop: values
        for (int inner = 1; inner <= 5; inner++) { 

            // Calculate the value
            result = outer * inner;

            // Format the output
            if (result < 10) {

                // Here, we need an extra space if the result is 1 digit
                System.out.print("    " + result);
            }
            else {
                System.out.print("   " + result);
            }

        }   // End for inner

        System.out.println();

    }   // End for outer

} // End of method main

} // End of class MultiplicationTable
```

Comment: Take a look at the `Scanner` class. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: Don't write redundant comments such as `// Beginning of method main`, `// End of something` etc.

Comment: Am I missing something?  Where are you looking at the input arguments?

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

int num;

while(true)
{
    try
    {
        System.out.print("Enter a number from 1 to 5: ");
        num = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
        if(num >= 1 && num <= 5)
             break;
        else
             System.out.println("Number must be between 1 and 5");
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Not an integer!");
    }
}
```

This will keep prompting for input until they enter an integer between 1 and 5. That integer will be saved in "num".